# How to show wordpress setting api validation error message?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a setting api for my new plugin. It has four `<input>` field and one `<select>` option. In that field , user can change value according to their requirement. But it must be valid value. Suppose , one `<input>` field support only integer value. so when user will fill that `<input>` field by string or by other things, it will show an error message. Please tell me how can i do that? Can you suggest any tutorial ?

Answer (score -2):

When using [`add_setting`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting) you can pass a `sanitize_callback` option as part of the array, this can contain the name of a function that is run which can contain your validation.

A similar method exists for JavaScript too, which you could use to validate the fields as well.

You asked for a tutorial too, here is one that outlines the method I've described: http://themeshaper.com/2013/04/29/validation-sanitization-in-customizer/

Comment: It is a nice tutorial but it is only discuss on Sanitization. Now error message is showing when i put wrong input.

Comment: Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: I asked for how to show validation error message? Suppose an `<input>` field only contain integer value but user is trying to put string. In this situation , `<input>` field will show an error message.